# Equivalent of Ctrl+Apostrophe in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, keyboard-shortcuts

In Microsoft Excel I frequently use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>'</kbd> (apostrophe) to copy the value from the cell above the current one. The same keystrokes in Google Sheets instead toggles the display of formula and I cannot find an equivalent shortcut to copy the value from the cell above. Any ideas please?

Comment: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/181110?hl=en

Comment: @krowe I can't see anything  in that link that can do what Ctrl+' does in Excel.

Comment: Which leads me to believe that it isn't possible.

Comment: Well I guess that's an answer then. 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> will copy the value from the above cell (not sure if/when they modified this functionality). You do not need to highlight the above row, just select the blank cell below the value you want to copy and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.

Comment: nice spot! This does appear to have been changed. It was formerly necessary to select the cell above.

Comment: CTRL+D Doesn't work if the line above is 'filtered out'

Answer (score 3):

Something that comes close is "Fill Down" (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>).

If you highlight the cell with the formula you want as well as the cell below it, then use this shortcut, it'll be just like you used the fill handle, without having to do all that mousing.

In fact, this may be more useful, because you could just put the formula on the first row, add all the rest of your data, then do the fill-down at the end.

Not as convenient as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>'</kbd>, but I've found it pretty useful lately.

Comment: It's no longer necessary to select the cell above as per the answer by erjiang https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/162035/26653

Answer (score 3):

If you're trying to copy down a value that you just entered/typed into the cell above, then you can use <kbd>F4</kbd>.

(F4 in Excel and Google Sheets does something along the lines of "repeat the last thing I just did".)

You might want to adjust your keyboard settings if you want to use this frequently so you don't have to hit <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd> every time since on most new computers the function keys are assigned to system functions (e.g. volume, app switcher, etc.).

Comment: hmmm not bad. This only works if you have just typed the number above though, so won't work in all scenarios but it's pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

First highlight the range where you are going fill with data, including the row/cell with the initial data. Enter the initial data, (on Windows) press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> (to get to the last row in the range) then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.

This will copy down all values by column.

Answer (score 0):

You can also click on the bottom right corner of the cell that contains the value you want to copy down, and when it changes to a small square you can drag it down to the cell below (or to the cell(s) right,left, above. Also, for text, typing in an initial letter will often "fill" the string.

Answer (score -1):

1. Shade cell above,
2. Hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> key and shade your target cell (or use the mouse to shade both cells),
3. Type <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>.  You're done!

Comment: Already suggested in the answer by ale https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/88613/26653; but welcome to Web Application on StackExchange!

Answer (score -2):

Are you wanting to copy the value because you only want to paste values? If so, then copy works just as it always does (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>)  and then the shortcut for pasting values only is

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>

Comment: The Asker presumably already knows about the "old fashioned" copy-paste. That's quite a few more keystrokes than `Ctrl-'`, though.

Comment: the only reason i mentioned that is because of specifically paste values only is slightly different than excel

Comment: Yeah I know about copy and paste values thanks. I'm after a quicker way to copy the value from the cell above. In Excel this is only 2 keystrokes.